# I am trying to make a list of all the logged in users for all of my windows servers

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, import-csv

I am trying to use powershell to take a list of server names and list all the folders in `c:\users`.

I want to write it to a file eventually, but for now I'm just trying to list them to the console.

```
$m = import-csv -Path .\serverlist.csv
    
$m | Foreach-Object { 
    $flist = Invoke-Command -Computername $_ -ScriptBlock {
        Get-Childitem -Path C:\users -Directory 
    } 
    write-host $flist
}
```

When I try to run the script, I get

```
Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, 
or pass URI objects instead of strings.
At C:\Users\omurac\Desktop\scripts\TestSnip\ImportorEachObject.ps1:4 char:32
+ ...  { $flist = Invoke-Command -Computername $_ -ScriptBlock {Get-Childit ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

If I do a write host from the $m variable, it shows a list of:

```
Name= server1
name=server2
nAME= SERVER3
```

ETC...

Is there a way to make sure that it passes the items from the csv as a string?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Change `Invoke-Command -Computername $_` to `Invoke-Command -Computername $_.Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a full-text explanation I found easier to re-code it with some comments for a better example:

```
# Import CSV. Consider if it has headers or not, you can use parameters to play with them. Lets imagine CSV is something like this:
# ServerName
# localhost
# localhost
# localhost

$servers = Import-Csv -Path .\serverlist.csv

# this goes thru each server read from the CSV. By default, first row is treated as header.
foreach ($line in $servers)
{ 
    # When calling the computername, you refer the line, and to the particular column name. here we assume it is called "ServerName"
    $result = Invoke-Command -Computername $line.ServerName -ScriptBlock {
        Get-Childitem -Path C:\Users -Directory 
    } 
    # You used a write-host, what is intended for a string output.
    # As you used a Get-ChildItem, you will get an array of values. Easy & Nice way to display it is using a Format-Table output
    $result | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the list of computers, it's best to use `Invoke-Command` like this

```
$serverlist = Import-Csv -Path .\serverlist.csv

$folderlist = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverlist.name -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Childitem -Path C:\users -Directory 
}
```

This will run against each server asynchronously (up to 32 by default in windows powershell 5.1) versus one at a time in a `foreach` loop.

Among the properties returned by default is `PSComputerName` so that you know which folders belong to which server. Here is the full list of default members returned by the above code.

```
Name               MemberType  
----               ----------  
GetType            Method      
ToString           Method      
BaseName           NoteProperty
LinkType           NoteProperty
Mode               NoteProperty
PSChildName        NoteProperty
PSComputerName     NoteProperty
PSDrive            NoteProperty
PSIsContainer      NoteProperty
PSParentPath       NoteProperty
PSPath             NoteProperty
PSProvider         NoteProperty
PSShowComputerName NoteProperty
RunspaceId         NoteProperty
Target             NoteProperty
Attributes         Property    
CreationTime       Property    
CreationTimeUtc    Property    
Exists             Property    
Extension          Property    
FullName           Property    
LastAccessTime     Property    
LastAccessTimeUtc  Property    
LastWriteTime      Property    
LastWriteTimeUtc   Property    
Name               Property    
Parent             Property    
Root               Property
```

Once you have collected the information in `$folderlist` you can look at it, export, etc.

Another thing I wanted to point out/recommend is the naming of variables. It's very easy to overlook a singular vs plural variable and we see it all the time a loop that looks like this

```
foreach($username in $usernames){do something on $usernames}
```

or vice versa, so a common practice is to name them descriptive like in my example. `$serverlist` and `$folderlist` make it easy to see what's in them.

Comment: This is also a great solution.  It was tough to choose. I used the first answer to complete my task, so technically it was the answer, but anyone reading this in the future, this guys solution works, and is probably more elegant.